# Excel macro: Add data to existing named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range "ABC", range is ("A1", "A3", "A5"). Now I need to use Macro to extend the range to ("A1", "A3", "A5", "A7"), that is, adding "A7" to the existing named range "ABC".

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Application.Union(Range("BLAH"), Range("A7")).Name = "BLAH"
```

Comment: Addendum if he would like to add a his current selection to his named range 

Application.Union(Range("ABC"), Selection).Name = "ABC"

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted.@Tim Williams

Comment: It is continuously giving this error - Method Union of Object _Application failed.